# Activity name not showing in Google Analytics active screen name

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have many activities in my app. I am setting screen name for all the activities in a xml file. But in Google Analytics active screen name its showing fully qualified name instead of the name given by me? How to do this? Please help.

[image]

Comment: post the code you are using to do this along with your question.

Comment: image added. please check.

Comment: Have you created xml directory in resources ?, your screen name xml file should be in res/xml/screen_names.xml.